# CSS: Trying to make button within form look the same as button outside of form

Tags: html, css, forms

The button within a form seems to have significantly more padding around it than the one outside of the form. I am trying to make the within-form button equal to the without-form button.

HTML/PHP

```
<?php 
        if (!(isset($_SESSION["sessionID"]))){
            echo "<button onClick='handleSignInClick()' id='sign_in_button' class='btn'>Sign In</button>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<form action='handler_sign_out.php' method='post' class='remove_padding'><input type='submit' class='btn' value='Sign Out'></form>";
        }

    ?>
```

CSS

```
.remove_padding{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.btn {
    border: none; 
    background-color: inherit;
    font-size: 16px; 
    text-align: center;
    color: #3C3C3C;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "sans-serif";
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: #eee;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted does not show the described difference. There must be other styles applied to your actual markup that you did not include in the example.
Maybe some margin is applied to the `input` element but not the `button` element?

Comment: @HansSpieß Yes, i have actually solved this now by changing "<input type...." to "<button..." for the button within a form. That solved it. I didn't realise that they rendered differently.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you put a fixed width on your .btn class, both buttons get the same width.
You were actually not right when you thought it had to do with padding.
The problem was actually caused by the value inside of the button.

'Sign in'
'Sign out'

Do you see the difference? 'Sign out' is actually a wider string. That is why the button size was bigger than the 'Sign in' button.
I put a width:100px; on the .btn class so the width of the button is exactly the same.

Also some others notes. Your way setting up margin/padding in css is unpractical.

Your code:

```
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
```

Try writing your margin/padding like the next example.

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

You can set up your margin and padding like the next examples.

```
margin: 0 1px 2px 3px;
```

This is exactly the same as:

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: 1px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
margin-left: 3px;
```

The same counts for padding. I hope I had helped you with this and sorry for giving you feedback on the code you specifically did not ask for. I hope you don't mind and pick this up!

Comment: Consider including the applicable HTML with your question.